# Cocos2D file not found?

Tags: ios, error-handling, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, chipmunk

I downloaded cocos2d, the latest version. I added the folders 'cocos2d' 'cocosdenshion' 'external' 'cocoslive' and 'experimental' to my project folder, then I dragged them to my project without clicking add to destination group project button.

But when I build the project, I get an error: 'vorbis/ivorbiscodec.h' file not found in ivorbisfile_example.c on this line:

```
#include <vorbis/ivorbiscodec.h>
```

If I comment it out, then this line has the same type of warning:

```
#include <vorbis/ivorbisfile.h>
```

I can't comment that out otherwise there is like 50 errors!

Anyway, I look in the hierarchy of folder and the file is indeed there. I am not sure what the vorbis/ part is **but the file ivorbiscodec.h is indeed in the project and in finder of the projects folder.**

I deleted the Box2D and Chipmunk folders in the external folder in finder and in the project if that makes any difference.

Does anyone have any idea why I am getting this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make something sure: Did you check 'Copy items to destinations group's folder (if needed)'?

[image]

> I deleted the Box2D and Chipmunk folders in the external folder in finder and in the project if that makes any difference.

This statement then makes a lot of sense, because the files couldn't be located and it would throw the errors.

(You could also right click the files inside Xcode and hit `Show in Finder` to verify their existence.

---

But on a side note: Cocos2D comes with a `install-templates.sh` script that you can use to natively include some Cocos2D project templates in Xcode. I would recommend you to do that and create Cocos2D projects from inside Xcode as follows:

[image]

Comment: I did not click add to destination group folder. I added the files to finder first, then dragged them from my project's folder into my Xcode 4 project. Also, I am using Cocos2D in a UIKit app. 
I am currently having issues of exactly what folders to drag in from the Cocos2D library. I do not need Box2D or Chipmunk, I just need Cocos2D and thats it. I just need to know which cocos2d folders I need from the folder I downloaded from the cocos2d website. What folders do I need in particular (please be specific), also remember that I don't need Box2D or Chipmunk!

Thanks!!!!

Comment: Did you ever figure out why this was happening? It's happening to me right now with ShareKit.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem,can you please help me?

Comment: any luck solving this issue?